# Codeigniter insert_batch fail weird array becomes string

Tags: codeigniter

So now I am passing a json and here is the result of `echo '<pre>' . var_export($data, true) . '</pre>';`:

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'booking_id' => 99,
        'item_type' => '67',
        'sales_item_seq' => '1',
        'package_item_id' => '0',
        'package_item_seq' => '0',
        'package_group' => '0',
        'package_group_rowspan' => '0',
        'package_group_subdata_rowspan' => '0',
        'channel_id' => '380',
        'name_of_channel_programme' => '123',
        'schedule_from' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'schedule_to' => '0000-00-00 23:59:59',
        'no_of_unit' => '123.00',
        'exposure_inside_per_unit' => '',
        'exposure_duration' => '123',
        'advertising_offier' => '0.00',
        'special_discount' => '0',
        'net' => '0.00',
        't_n_c' => '',
        'remark' => '',
        'status' => '1',
        'create_datetime' => '2018-11-14 17:00:33',
        'update_datetime' => '2018-11-14 17:00:33',
        'channel' => '2',
        'package_name' => '',
        'sale_item_name' => 'hello',
        'cat_id' => '1',
        'aftersales_type' => '',
        'typing_guide' => '',
        'position' => '',
        'platform_des' => 'hello',
        'nature_des' => 'hello',
        'unit_des' => 'Account',
      ),
...
...
...
      9 => 
      array (
        'booking_id' => 99,
        'item_type' => '59',
        'sales_item_seq' => '1',
        'package_item_id' => '0',
        'package_item_seq' => '0',
        'package_group' => '0',
        'package_group_rowspan' => '0',
        'package_group_subdata_rowspan' => '0',
        'channel_id' => '0',
        'name_of_channel_programme' => 'N/A',
        'schedule_from' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'schedule_to' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'no_of_unit' => '123.00',
        'exposure_inside_per_unit' => 'N/A',
        'exposure_duration' => 'N/A',
        'advertising_offier' => '1000.00',
        'special_discount' => '100',
        'net' => '0.00',
        't_n_c' => '',
        'remark' => '',
        'status' => '1',
        'create_datetime' => '2018-11-14 17:00:33',
        'update_datetime' => '2018-11-14 17:00:33',
        'channel' => '',
        'package_name' => '',
        'sale_item_name' => 'Service Charge',
        'cat_id' => '7',
        'aftersales_type' => '',
        'typing_guide' => 'N/A',
        'position' => 'N/A',
        'platform_des' => 'N/A',
        'nature_des' => 'Operations',
        'unit_des' => 'Campaign',
      ),
      10 => 
      array (
        'booking_id' => 99,
        'item_type' => '0',
        'sales_item_seq' => '0',
        'package_item_id' => '161',
        'package_item_seq' => '0',
        'package_group' => '1',
        'package_group_rowspan' => '6',
        'package_group_subdata_rowspan' => '1',
        'channel_id' => '39',
        'name_of_channel_programme' => 'hello',
        'schedule_from' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'schedule_to' => '0000-00-00 23:59:59',
        'no_of_unit' => '1.00',
        'exposure_inside_per_unit' => '0',
        'exposure_duration' => '',
        'advertising_offier' => '180000.00',
        'special_discount' => '100',
        'net' => '0.00',
        't_n_c' => '',
        'remark' => '',
        'status' => '1',
        'create_datetime' => '2018-11-14 17:00:33',
        'update_datetime' => '2018-11-14 17:00:33',
        'channel' => 'Catch',
        'package_name' => 'hello',
        'sale_item_name' => 'hello',
        'cat_id' => '1',
        'aftersales_type' => '',
        'typing_guide' => 'Name of Programme',
        'position' => '',
        'platform_des' => 'hello',
        'nature_des' => 'Live',
        'unit_des' => 'Live Segment',
        'package_id' => '28',
      ),
...
...
...
        'unit_des' => 'Video',
        'package_id' => '28',
      ),
    )
```

It looks fine to me when I view it on an online viewer. and after `$this->db->insert_batch('table_name',$data)` here is the error returned saying there is `Array` in the code.

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Array' at line 1

And I can find it at the end of the followings (think this is the raw output of the `insert_batch`):

```
    INSERT INTO `table_name` () VALUES 
                ( 
                            '0.00', 
                            '', 
                            100, 
                            '1', 
                            '2', 
                            '380', 
                            '2018-11-14 17:06:46', 
                            '123', 
                            '', 
                            '67', 
                            '123', 
                            'Access Right', 
                            '0.00', 
                            '123.00', 
                            '0', 
                            '0', 
                            '0', 
                            '0', 
                            '0', 
                            '', 
                            'hello', 
                            '', 
                            '', 
                            'hello', 
                            '1', 
                            '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                            '0000-00-00 23:59:59', 
                            '0', 
                            '1', 
                            '', 
                            '', 
                            'Account', 
                            '2018-11-14 17:06:46' 
                ) 
                , 
...
...
...
                ( 
                            '1000.00', 
                            '', 
                            100, 
                            '7', 
                            '', 
                            '0', 
                            '2018-11-14 17:06:46', 
                            'N/A', 
                            'N/A', 
                            '59', 
                            'N/A', 
                            'Operations', 
                            '0.00', 
                            '123.00', 
                            '0', 
                            '0', 
                            '0', 
                            '0', 
                            '0', 
                            '', 
                            'N/A', 
                            'N/A', 
                            '', 
                            'Service Charge', 
                            '1', 
                            '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                            '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                            '100', 
                            '1', 
                            '', 
                            'N/A', 
                            'Campaign', 
                            '2018-11-14 17:06:46' 
                ) 
                , 
                array
```

I have no idea why there becomes an `array` for all the elements from 10 th onwards. 
Please let me know if you require more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're array indexes doesn't match. 1 - 9 doesn't have package_id

---

You may add this to ensure all array has package_id index:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$val){ if (!isset($val['package_id'])) $val['package_id'] = null; });
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response @ACD ! If that is the case then I might need to create to query for those with and without the package_id. Let me try and respond back to you after.

Comment: please see edit. You don't have to create another query for those array without package_id, you just have to add the lacking index.